# Ruby regex delete space

Tags: ruby, regex

Hello and excuse me again

I need a REGEX for delete the character space (" "). If this character is not followed for other space character.

```
Example String

"This  is  a  ex am ple" 

Result 

"This  is  a  example"
```

I was trying this REGEXES:

```
string.gsub(/\s{1}/,"")
```

Also I thought in submatches replace for I don´t know as use it in ruby

```
string.gsub(/(\w)( )(\w)/,/\1\3/)
```

However throw a exception.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have small error in second gsub. Try this:

```
string.gsub(/(\w)( )(\w)/, '\1\3')
```

I checked this on your example, it works for me.

Comment: Thank you very much. I use your solution

Answer (score 4):

try with this:

```
print "This  is  a  ex am ple".gsub(/(?<=\w)\s(?=\w)/, '')
```

output:

```
This  is  a  example
```

Comment: I don't think (?<=\S)\s(?=\S) is a good idea. It maybe combine non-alphabet & alphabet together. Sorry PraVn, I change it back.

Answer (score 0):

Try this reg expression:

```
string.gsub(/(?<!\s)\s(?!\s)/, '');
```

Input:

```
"This     is    a  ex am ple"
```

Output:

```
"This     is    a  example"
```

Comment: Excuse me The Regex in my opinion is correct. However when I try this regex I obtain -> "This is a ex am ple" (Excuse me I obtain same result)

Comment: I misunderstood your question, now i got it. I modified the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
string.gsub( /(\w) (\w)/, '\1\2' )
```

What do you want to happen to a space at the start?